# Can Sophia see the holographic projections or are they only visible to us (audience)?

Tags: plot-explanation, assassins-creed

In [Assassin's Creed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2094766/), Desmond is attached to a machine to synchronize with his past ancestors.

We can see holographic projections in action and adventure scenes.

[image]

Can Sophia see these holographic projections or are they only visible to us (audience)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use projections on a cloud of dust or smoke. 
 That means it's visible in universe, to all the characters.

What Sophia can't see is the hallucinations all the Assassins see of their past selves when not connected to the Animus machine.